# How can I check weather Ubuntu use nouveau or any other graphic driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

Since I have 4 GPUs

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] (rev a1)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] (rev a1)
83:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] (rev a1)
84:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] (rev a1)
```

and here is the content of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe`

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device

    "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

My question is what the current graphic driver this machine is using?

Answer (score 0):

Read the log file in /var/log. Look for name like Xorg.0.log. that will display driver. Will require root permission or sudo to read that.

Other ideas to run in a terminal:

1. lspci in terminal will show if you have nvidia card and
2. /sbin/lsmod  will show kernnel modules

These may want sudo first, possibly.